# Adding nested numbers to grouped total in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an existing array structure similar to this but I'm trying to end up adding all of the totals for each day and week for downloads and saves into the type level of this array as shown here for an example:

```
    team1=> array:[
        member1=> array:[
            titleA=> array:[
                typeA=> array:[
                    detailTypeA=> array:[
                        downloaded=>array:[
                            this_week=>4
                            today=>70
                        ]
                        saved=>array:[
                            this_week=>7
                            today=>20
                        ]
                    ]
                    detailTypeB=> array:[
                        downloaded=>array:[
                            this_week=>150
                            today=>6
                        ]
                        saved=>array:[
                            this_week=>120
                            today=>5
                        ]
                    ]
                    contestNumbers=>array:[
                        downloaded=>array:[
                            this_week=>154
                            today=>76
                        ]
                        saved=>array:[
                            this_week=>127
                            today=>25
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

I'm running into issues here where there is an undefined index of 'downloaded' which I can't figure out and I'm not getting all of my numbers added up at the type level

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    <?
    foreach ($this->contestData as $teamNumber => &$teamData){
        if($teamNumber!=='contestNumbers'){
            foreach ($teamData as $memberNumber => &$memberData) {
                if($memberNumber!=='contestNumbers'){
                    foreach ($memberData as $titleNumber => &$titleData) {
                        if($titleNumber !== 'contestNumbers') {
                            foreach ($titleData as $type => &$typeData) {
                                if ($type !== 'contestNumbers') {
                                    foreach ($typeData as $detailType => &$detailTypeData) {

                                        $typeData['contestNumbers'] = [];

                                        if(!isset($detailTypeData['downloaded'])) $detailTypeData['downloaded'] = [];
                                        foreach ($this->shifts as $shiftTime){
                                            if(!isset($detailTypeData['downloaded'][$shiftTime]))
                                                $detailTypeData['downloaded'][$shiftTime] = 0;

                                            $typeData['contestNumbers']['downloaded'][$shiftTime] += $detailTypeData['downloaded'][$shiftTime];

                                        }

                                        if(!isset($detailTypeData['saved'])) $detailTypeData['saved'] = [];
                                        foreach ($this->shifts as $shiftTime){
                                            if(!isset($detailTypeData['saved'][$shiftTime]))
                                                $detailTypeData['saved'][$shiftTime] = 0;

                                            $typeData['contestNumbers']['saved'][$shiftTime] += $detailTypeData['saved'][$shiftTime];

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Which line does it complain about?

Comment: I believe it's this one specifically ```$typeData['contestNumbers']['downloaded'][$shiftTime] += $detailTypeData['downloaded'][$shiftTime];```

Comment: @El_Vanja but I don't want to change my loop much or at all if possible

Comment: The error will specify the exact line, so there shouldn't be any doubt. Have you tried dumping those array to see what they hold in each iteration?

Comment: Yes if I remove the lines where I try to put it into the totals for ```contestNumbers``` each iteration of the actual numbers is correct and matches the main structure I posted above

Comment: @el_vanja I hope I made sense with that

Comment: What does `$this->shifts` look like?

Comment: ```['this_week', 'today' ]```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your loop. This is your main culprit: `$typeData['contestNumbers'] = [];`. In each iteration you are overwriting the data you previously stored under this index. This needs to be wrapped inside a `!isset` condition.

Next, you forgot to exclude the `contestNumbers` index at `$detailType` level (like you did with all the other loops when you check that the index is not equal to `contestNumbers`).

Another point of improvement is not looping twice over the shifts array, but rather doing all the job in a single loop. Altogether, this is what your inner `foreach` should look like:

```php
foreach ($typeData as $detailType => &$detailTypeData) {
    // this is an alternative to wrapping the rest of the code in
    // an opposite if condition, as you do with the other loops
    if ($detailType === 'contestNumbers') {
        // just skip this element and move on to the next iteration
        continue;
    }
    // initialize the fields for totals
    if (!isset($typeData['contestNumbers'])) {
        $typeData['contestNumbers']['downloaded'] = [];
        $typeData['contestNumbers']['saved'] = [];
    }
    // 'downloaded' and 'saved' are hardcoded values; no need to loop over shifts twice
    foreach ($shifts as $shiftTime){
        // initialize the fields for totals per shift
        if(!isset($typeData['contestNumbers']['downloaded'][$shiftTime])) {
            $typeData['contestNumbers']['downloaded'][$shiftTime] = 0;
        }
        if(!isset($typeData['contestNumbers']['saved'][$shiftTime])) {
            $typeData['contestNumbers']['saved'][$shiftTime] = 0;
        }
        // add current value
        $typeData['contestNumbers']['downloaded'][$shiftTime] += $detailTypeData['downloaded'][$shiftTime];
        $typeData['contestNumbers']['saved'][$shiftTime] += $detailTypeData['saved'][$shiftTime];
    }
}
```

Though you might seriously rethink the whole design for next year's contest. When your arrays get this deep, it's easy to create a mess.